# Prune before join vs prune after join vs prune during join

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the best practice when one needs to do a table join on a table subset? i.e. Consider the following queries:

```sql
WITH pruned AS (
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE timestamp >= TIMESTAMP('some timestamp')
)
SELECT bar.* FROM bar
INNER JOIN foo
ON bar.id = pruned.id
```

```sql
SELECT bar.* FROM bar
INNER JOIN foo
ON bar.id = foo.id
WHERE foo.timestamp >= TIMESTAMP('some timestamp')
```

```sql
SELECT bar.* FROM bar
INNER JOIN foo
ON foo.timestamp >= TIMESTAMP('some timestamp')
AND bar.id = foo.id
```

I'm guessing that last one is technically the most performant approach? Perhaps it depends on the tables' data but I'm guessing BigQuery stores the `pruned` table temporarily in the first approach so it's the worse one?

Comment: For those voting to close this. Even if it's opinion based it'd be nice to get some explanation around the three different queries and how they would work. The first one might be obvious, but as for the later two, it's unclear how BQ would go about executing those statements.